# Check if knight move between two points is valid

Tags: c++, algorithm, chess

I am doing a chess project in C++.  I am trying to check for a valid knight move in a 2D array.

I've got the old position of the player `this->getLocX(),this->getLocY()` variables (where the player was) and I have `x,y` (this is where the player wants to move his knight into).

How can you check validity in the best way? Here's my solution but I want to know if theres a better way.

```
if (x == this->getLocX() + 1 && y == this->getLocY() + 2 || x == this->getLocX() - 1 && y == this->getLocY() + 2 || y == this->getLocY() + 1 && x == this->getLocX() + 2 || y == this->getLocY() + 1 && x == this->getLocX() - 2  || x == this->getLocX() - 1 && y == this->getLocY() + 2 || x == this->getLocX() + 1 && y == this->getLocY() - 2 || y == this->getLocY() - 1 && x == this->getLocX() - 2 || y == this->getLocY() - 1 && x == this->getLocX() + 2 || x == this->getLocX() - 1 && y == this->getLocY() - 2)
{
    //Move is vaid
}
```

Comment: A valid knight's move is one where the absolute value of the change in x and the absolute value of the change in y are 1 and 2 or 2 and 1. And where the move is confined to the board.

Comment: Could you right me the condition please? I am not sure I understand

Comment: @Z.Zadon No, we cannot write the condition for you: SO is not a coding service.  Also, the problem of a legal knight's move is covered quite well on line, including on this site.  We expect you to take due diligence to find or create a solution before you post here for help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: I don't understand what I did wrong. I posted my solution here and it works good but I just want to check if theres a better way.. its not like I just asked you to write me a code ;(

Comment: The absolute change in x means the difference between `x` and `this->getLocX()` as a positive value. Same thing for the absolute change in y. It's a valid knight move if one of those is 1 and the other is 2.

Comment: Alright thanks I managed to do it :), solved

Comment: If you're looking to improve efficiency, ditch the 2d array in favor of a 1-d array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My try:

```
abs((X0 - X1) * (Y0 - Y1)) == 2
```

For efficiency, the absolute value can be computed branchless.

Comment: I like this solution +1, but you miss the check if the destination is inside the board (as well as all other solutions so far).

Comment: @AlKepp: this didn't seem to be requested in the question, possibly handled elsewhere or just implicitly achieved.

Answer (score 1):

Here a variants to check the validity, checking the horizontal and vertical distance:

```
bool isValidKnight2(int getLocX,int getLocY, int x,int y)
{
    int dx = abs(getLocX - x); 
    int dy = abs(getLocY - y); 
    return (dx == 1 && dy==2 || dx  == 2 && dy==1); 
}
```

And here one checking the horizontal and vertical move against a [set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) of allowed possibitlities:

```
bool isValidKnight3(int getLocX,int getLocY, int x,int y)
{
    static set<pair<int,int>> valid={{1,2},{2,1}}; 
    return (valid.find(make_pair(abs(getLocX - x), abs(getLocY - y)))!=valid.end()); 
}
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/RSbOKt)